# How to upgrade pip3 on Debian 12 (Bookworm)?

Tags: linux, debian, pip, debian-bookworm

The `pip3` binary on my freshly upgraded Debian 12 still isn't new enough to support flags `--json` and `--include-injected`, which I need to be able to use [ansible module `community.general.pipx`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/pipx_module.html).

The old-fashioned way of upgrading it fails:

```
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS
distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python
installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.

hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

Which is also the reason why I need to use the `pipx` Ansible module in the first place.

- How to break out from this chicken-and-egg problem?
- Is it reasonably safe to use `--break-system-package` in this particular case?
- Or, would it make sense to install a new version of `pip` separately using CLI `pipx` first in a virtual environment and then let the Ansible module use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `pip` and `pipx` are separate programs. pip is a general purpose Python package manager, it can work systemwide (I mean... it *used to*), or in a virtual environment. pipx focuses specifically on installing binaries (not libraries), and it works by creating an isolated virtual environment and running pip inside it.

`--json` and `--include-injected` are flags of pipx (specifically "pipx list"), not flags of pip. Your problem is that pipx is too old, not that pip is too old.

Ansible [uses the flags here](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/40809ed95380b0f056093bad644073f80aef07a9/plugins/modules/pipx_info.py#L118-L130).

In order to upgrade pipx safely, you must find out how you originally installed it. Was it installed as a Debian package (with dpkg and/or apt), or was it installed manually with pip? Find its location, e.g.:

```
$ which pipx
/usr/bin/pipx
```

Check if dpkg recognizes that file and knows which Debian package it belongs to.

```
$ dpkg --search /usr/bin/pipx
pipx: /usr/bin/pipx
```

If you see that, great. Just do a normal system upgrade, and you'll get the new version. (This is unlikely because if it were so easy then you wouldn't even be asking this question.)

```
$ dpkg --search /usr/bin/pipx
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/pipx
```

If you see that, it means you previously installed it manually with `sudo pip install pipx` or similar, back when that was still allowed. In this case, your goal should be to completely uninstall the old pipx, along with any of its dependencies that were also installed manually, and then install the official [Debian pipx package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=pipx&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

This command prints the Debian package owner of each file in /usr/lib/python*. Files which do not belong to any Debian package will print an error. Those errors will tell you the previously manually installed packages which probably need to be manually uninstalled.

```
$ find /usr/lib/python* -type f ! -name '*.pyc' -exec dpkg --search {} + 2>&1
```

I think the correct way to uninstall them is with `sudo pip uninstall --break-system-packages pipx` (and so on for other packages). In this case `--break-system-packages` should be fine because you're just cleaning up a mess that was created before the flag existed. BUT MAKE SURE you only uninstall packages which had the "no path found matching pattern" error. NOT the packages which are already recognized by dpkg.

When the command doesn't print any "no path found matching pattern" errors anymore, install the official Debian pipx package using `sudo apt-get install pipx`. If it works, you're done. If it prints any conflicts with existing files, the old pipx probably wasn't completely uninstalled.